# casting numpy array into square array by comparing subarray

Tags: python, arrays, numpy

I have and Array in shape `(2000,256,2)` and I want to cast it into the shape `(2000,256,256)` by comparing the sub arrays in the 3rd dimension.

for example:

```
Indexing=[[[0,0],[0,0],[0,1],...,[1,0],[1,0],...,[5,3],...,[NaN,NaN]],...,]
```

And if `Indexing[0][0]==Indexing[0][1]` then `Outputarray[0][0][1]=Outputarray[0][1][0]=True`

My first attempt so far looks like

```
Outputarray = Indexing[:,:,None]==Indexing[:,None,:]
```

It almost does what I want. The problems that come up are that each entry of the array gets compared instead of the array as a whole so the Outputdimension is `(2000,256,256,2)` and all entries that are padded with `NaN` in the `Indexing` should become `False` instead of beeing compared.

so`[NaN,NaN]==[NaN,Nan]=False` instead of what my code does currently `[NaN,NaN]==[NaN,NaN]=True`

How can I do this without iterating over each entry, so that the code is still effiecient?

Comment: In numpy code we like to see `Indexing=np.array([[...]])` (it's not a list), and `Indexing[0,0]` syntax.  `[0][0]` often works but is visually cluttered.

Comment: `Indexing[:,:,None,0]==Indexing[:,None,:,1]` should produce a (2000,256,256).  It doesn't deal with the `nan`.  Nothing equals `nan`, not even itself.

Comment: There are a set of `np.nan*` functions that help processing arrays with `nan`.  Usually they replace the `nan` values with something that doesn't cause problems, such as 0 or 1, and apply the operation.  Off hand I don't see an equality test though.